# UICollectionView DidDeselectItemAtIndexPath method not called in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've got a collection view listing a bunch of videos and tapping any of them will push navigation controller which contain a custom player view to play the video. Tapping the close button on the customer player view will pop the current controller and go back to the video list controller.

Also when tapping one of the cells that cell will become gray color. When going back and tapping another cell from the video list, I want to deselect the previously selected cell and make it back to white and make the newly selected cell to be gray color.

The problem is, didDeselectCellAtIndexPath method is NEVER called. The previously selected cell does get deselected, which I could see from the print of the selected indexPath. However the delegation method never gets called thus backgroundColor never changes back to white. It looks like multiple cells are selected, despite allowsMultipleSesection is already set to false.

Following configuration is set:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
collectionView?.delegate = self
collectionView?.dataSource = self
collectionView?.allowsSelection = true
collectionView?.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

Here is my collectionView methods and delegation methods:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! PreviewCell
    cell.snapShotImageView.image = videoInfoArray[indexPath.item].previewImg
    cell.durationLabel.text = videoInfoArray[indexPath.item].lengthText()
    cell.dateLabel.text = videoInfoArray[indexPath.item].dateAddedText()
    return cell
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PreviewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 240, green: 240, blue: 240)
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoInfoArray[indexPath.item].path)
    let vc = VideoController()
    self.videoController = vc
    vc.url = url
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PreviewCell
    
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.captionFileLabel.backgroundColor = .white
    print("Deselect called!!! This line should be printed, but it never happens!!!!")
}
```

[image: This is the video player view controller]

[image: After the controller was popped, the list controller shows two cells selected, but only one of them is selected. The DeselectionItemAtIndexPath not called, even though there is ONLY ONE currently selected cell.]

Comment: Why your delegate methods have the keyword `override`? I mean, what Class are you Subclassing? If the parent Class doesn't implement a delegate method, any subclass won't be able to do it either.

Comment: @zero UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, I'm subclassing or adopting these classes or protocols. When I delete "override", it pops up error that prompts me to add "override".

Comment: Try this below your `collectionView` configuration: `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false`

Comment: @zero Dude please write an answer below, copying the first comment you made "If the parent class doesn't implement a delegate method, any subclass won't either" and I will accept it as the correct answer. It was your hint that saved my life. Yes, I did not adopt UICollectionViewDelegate, which is the only one that will do the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent Class doesn't implement a delegate method, any Subclass won't be able to do it either.

Please make sure the Class you are Subclassing implements it.

Answer (score 1):

Let the cell handle its background color. 
Just add the following to your "PreviewCell" class:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        // TODO: replace .red & .blue with desired colors
        backgroundColor = isSelected ? .red : .blue
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves the problem of David. But you solved mine so I marked as useful.
Overriding `isSelected` prop is kinda equal of `setSelected(_:_:)` method for `UITableViewCell` class.
I had a problem on deselecting items and changing UI. I solved by overriding that prop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation I can understand that this method gets called when the user selected cell X, and then selects cell Y. Now cell X deselected and the method will be called.

Save an index of the selected cell before you move to the new view controller, and when you come back to the collection view controller, deselect the cell programmatically and then run inside your own function what you wanted to run in the deselect delegate method.

> The collection view calls this method when the user tries to deselect an item in the collection view. It does not call this method when you programmatically deselect items.
>   If you do not implement this method, the default return value is true.

Answer (score 0):

`didDeselectItemAt`  is called when `allowsMultipleSelection` is set to true.

> backgroundColor never changes back to white

even when your previously selected cell does get deselected, because your view doesnt get updated. You need to update your collection view cells view everytime you go back. You can refresh complete UICollectionView in viewWillAppear of your collectionViewController subclass. You can also use @entire method to deselect all selected indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `didSelectItemAt` method, call the `deselectItem(at:animated:)` method on the collection view.